# Simplification of a product of four $SU(N)$ structure constants.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, physics, mathematical-physics

I've recently run into the following product of $\mathfrak{su}(N)$ structure constants (defined with skew-Hermitian generators $t^a$, so that $[t^a,t^b]={f^{ab}}_ct^c$):
$$
f^{ijk}{f_i}^{ab}{f_j}^{cd}{f_k}^{ef}
$$
which has defied all of my attempts at simplification. Can this be rewritten in terms of invariants or smaller products of generators/structure constants? I've only found one reference containing a similar quantity, but it was given in the context of superalgebras. Is there any standard method to reduce larger products of structure constants?

Comment: Well, structure constants satisfy Jacobi's identity, so, you could try to use this, but I don't know if this helps much here.

Comment: Right, the only problem is that I need two structure constants with one contracted index. I can choose the first and any one of the latter three, but this leaves me in a similar situation. I’m hoping that, since the problem I’ve written is actually part of a sum over permutations of the indices a-f, that some symmetry of the larger problem may be used to reduce the sum. I just can’t really figure out the specifics quite yet, and either way I’m left with four structure constants.

Comment: You *do* appreciate the trivial su(2) limit for $f^{ijk}\to \epsilon^{ijk}$, namely $\epsilon^{acd}\epsilon^{bef}-\epsilon^{bcd}\epsilon^{aef} $, and its evident symmetries, right?

Comment: I do, but I'm unaware of any sort of generalization of
$$
\epsilon^{ijk}{\epsilon_i}^{ab}=\delta^{ja}\delta^{kb}-\delta^{jb}\delta^{ka}
$$
to other structure constants. I can't imagine that this holds exactly for $N>2$.

Comment: That is, unless there is some sort of determinant or generalized Kronecker delta for other $N$. I was originally looking for a Fierz-like relation for the adjoint representation. I suppose I could recast the structure constants as traces over fundamental generators and then use the Fierz relation, but this seems overly complicated.

Comment: The canonical go-to reference is *Group Theory Birdtracks, Lie’s, and Exceptional Groups* of Predrag  Cvitanović,  (Princeton, 2008).